# Neo4j Spring Data mapping to Java API stackoverflow

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

I am having a StackOverflowError Error when I am trying to map data from neo4j into Spring data. The project is using Lombok.

I am able to get Project with only one Use, That worked fine. But for a Project with two or more use, The error occur.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Error:

```
Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Project.java

```
@NodeEntity
@Data
//@JsonIgnoreProperties({"project","use"}) //also tried but same issue
public class Project {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Nullable
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"project","use"})
    @Relationship(type = "USED_FOR")
    List<ProjectUseRelation> usedFor = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Use.java

```
@NodeEntity
@Data
//@JsonIgnoreProperties({"project","use"}) //also tried but same issue
public class Use {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Nullable
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"project","use"})
    @Relationship(type = "USED_FOR", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    List<ProjectUseRelation> usedByProjects = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

ProjectUseRelation.java

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "USED_FOR")
@Data
public class ProjectUseRelation {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Nullable
    private String name;

    @StartNode
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"usedFor"})
    private Project project;

    @EndNode
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"usedByProjects"})
    private Use use;
}
```

Service.java

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Service{
private final Repository repository;
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Map<String, Object> graph(String id){
    //system correctly reached here
    Collection<Project> result = repository.graph(id);
    //system can't reach here
    return result;
    }
}
```

Repository.java

```
public interface Repository extends Neo4jRepository<Project,String>{
    @Query("MATCH map = (p:Project)-[]-(u:Use) WHERE p.id = {id} RETURN map")
    Collection<Project> graph(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

This now can return me single/multiple on-to-one relationships, but not single one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Is `ModelUseRelation` actually named `ProjectUseRelation`, or vice versa?

Comment: That was a type. Just fixed. Thank you.

Comment: The entity class is still named `ModelUseRelation`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to serialize your data to JSON, and your entities have circular dependencies (e.g., entity X has a field that references Y, and Y has a field that references X), then you must use the annotations `@JsonIgnoreProperties` or `@JsonIgnore`, where appropriate, to avoid `StackOverflowError`s during serialization.

Refer to the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#_a_note_on_json_serialization) for more details.

[UPDATE]

Your `Project` entity ignores the `ProjectUseRelation.project` field (during serialization) but does not ignore `ProjectUseRelation.use`.

And the `Use` entity ignores `ProjectUseRelation.use` but does not ignore `ProjectUseRelation.project`.

Therefore, a circular dependency still exists:

```
   Project.userFor
     -> ProjectUseRelation.use
     -> Use.usedByProjects
     -> ProjectUseRelation.project
     -> Project
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I did the @JsonIgnoreProperties already, Why this still happens? Also, This error does not occur when the return data is one-to-one relation on nodes. Can you explain a bit more? Thank you.

Comment: I did the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` already, Why this still happens? I even tried to put `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"project","use","usedFor","usedByProjects"})` for all `@Relationship` properties. But still getting the same error. 
Also, This error does not occur when the return data is one-to-one relation on nodes. Can you explain a bit more? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I added `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"project","use"})` on both node entity classes. Still the same issue.
Also I googled that the @JsonIgnoreProperties is class level annotation. So I also tried to put it on class level. Still the same issue.

Comment: Interesting. What if you used `@JsonIgnore` on `project` and `use` in `ProjectUseRelation`? Also, make sure you use the appropriate annotations (check their full class names) for whatever JSON serialization library you are using.

Comment: Still the same thing. `@JsonIgnore` would still give me the same issue. Again, The recursion does not happen when the returned relation is on-to-one. Or multiple one-to-one relation.

Comment: Are you using the Jackson library for serialization?

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out that the issue is with Lombok @Data annotation. If I comment out @Data annotation and write my own getters and setters, there will not be a Stack Overflow Error.